# Strange scroll bar in source code display

Tags: discussion, status-completed, code-formatting

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307635/undesired-rounding-of-datetime-in-sql-server) on SO in which one of my code snippets had some strange formatting issues.  The issues appear in the top-most code snippet.  Despite a bunch of effort, I could not resolve these formatting problems.

Most obviously, the horizontal scroll bar appears before the closing brace that ends the code snippet.  Additionally, the contents of the `using` block are not properly indented.

These issues are consistent across all versions of Firefox, IE, and Chrome that I've tried.

Comment: I fixed it for you by inserting an HTML comment to break the codeblock out of the last list item. I'm not sure if the behaviour you were seeing originally is by design or not, though.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even consider that the codeblock was being considered part of a list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug will be [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73799/code-so-bad-it-breaks-the-v-scroll-twice/74206#74206) in the next build, after which your original post (without Tim's workaround) would work as expected.