# Code so bad it breaks the v-scroll twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting

[What is the most EVIL code you have ever seen in a production enterprise environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434414/what-is-the-most-evil-code-you-have-ever-seen-in-a-production-enterprise-environm/434562#434562)

This answer has a code snipet (of purposefully bad code) that creates a double scroll (I guess it's a "div in a div" thing).

Shows fine in IE8 (!), but the double scroll thing is present in Firefox 3.6.13.[image]

---

**Update** for reference, the original text/code was:

- Some genius figured out that you can hook multiple form controls up to the same event handler. How did the programmer handle this?

  ```
  private void OperationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Button btn = (Button)sender;
      if (blnModeIsAddMc)
      {
          AddMcOperationKeyPress(btn);
      }
      else
      {
          string strToBeAppendedLater = string.Empty;
          if (btn.Name != "btnBS")
          {
              UpdateText();
          }
          if (txtEdit.Text.Trim() != "Error")
          {
              SaveFormState();
          }
          switch (btn.Name)
          {
              case "btnC":
                  ResetValues();
                  break;
              case "btnCE":
                  txtEdit.Text = "0";
                  break;
              case "btnBS":
                  if (!blnStartedNew)
                  {
                      string EditText = txtEdit.Text.Substring(0, txtEdit.Text.Length - 1);
                      DisplayValue((EditText == string.Empty) ? "0" : EditText);
                  }
                  break;
              case "btnPercent":
                  blnAfterOp = true;
                  if (GetValueDecimal(txtEdit.Text, out decCurrValue))
                  {
                      AddToTape(GetValueString(decCurrValue), (string)btn.Text, true, false);
                      decCurrValue = decResultValue * decCurrValue / intFormatFactor;
                      DisplayValue(GetValueString(decCurrValue));
                      AddToTape(GetValueString(decCurrValue), string.Empty, true, false);
                      strToBeAppendedLater = GetValueString(decResultValue).PadLeft(20)
                                                  + strOpPressed.PadRight(3);
                      if (arrLstTapeHist.Count == 0)
                      {
                          arrLstTapeHist.Add(strToBeAppendedLater);
                      }
                      blnEqualOccurred = false;
                      blnStartedNew = true;
                  }
                  break;
              case "btnAdd":
              case "btnSubtract":
              case "btnMultiply":
              case "btnDivide":
                  blnAfterOp = true;
                  if (txtEdit.Text.Trim() == "Error")
                  {
                      btnC.PerformClick();
                      return;
                  }
                  if (blnNumPressed || blnEqualOccurred)
                  {
                      if (GetValueDecimal(txtEdit.Text, out decCurrValue))
                      {
                          if (Operation())
                          {
                              AddToTape(GetValueString(decCurrValue), (string)btn.Text, true, true);
                              DisplayValue(GetValueString(decResultValue));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              AddToTape(GetValueString(decCurrValue), (string)btn.Text, true, true);
                              DisplayValue("Error");
                          }
                          strOpPressed = btn.Text;
                          blnEqualOccurred = false;
                          blnNumPressed = false;
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      strOpPressed = btn.Text;
                      AddToTape(GetValueString(0), (string)btn.Text, false, false);
                  }

                  if (txtEdit.Text.Trim() == "Error")
                  {
                      AddToTape("Error", string.Empty, true, true);
                      btnC.PerformClick();
                      txtEdit.Text = "Error";
                  }
                  break;
              case "btnEqual":
                  blnAfterOp = false;
                  if (strOpPressed != string.Empty || strPrevOp != string.Empty)
                  {
                      if (GetValueDecimal(txtEdit.Text, out decCurrValue))
                      {
                          if (OperationEqual())
                          {
                              DisplayValue(GetValueString(decResultValue));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              DisplayValue("Error");
                          }
                          if (!blnEqualOccurred)
                          {
                              strPrevOp = strOpPressed;
                              decHistValue = decCurrValue;
                              blnNumPressed = false;
                              blnEqualOccurred = true;
                          }
                          strOpPressed = string.Empty;
                      }
                  }
                  break;
              case "btnSign":
                  GetValueDecimal(txtEdit.Text, out decCurrValue);
                  DisplayValue(GetValueString(-1 * decCurrValue));
                  break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Same in Chrome 6 (Linux)

Comment: And Chrome 7 (WinXP)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is related to [this problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71305/strange-scroll-bar-in-source-code-display), though in this case the snippet is supposed to be part of the list, I think. It's possible to "fix" it for this post by removing the empty line in the code, but this is a highly annoying Markdown parser bug, +1.

Comment: I can't understand why IE8 got it right. It must be that they had it double-wrong, thus making it appear right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the hang of fixing Markdown issues :)

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Thanks. I never really thought of the extra layer of complexity involved in Markdown (on top of the usual cross-browser HTML fun). So, your work is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

It's caused by the blank line before the `if` statement in the screenshot. I removed it.

I've indeed seen this before. Markdown can't properly handle blank lines in code blocks inside a list. Apart from breaking the structure as you found out, it also inserts double blank line for every blank line.

Example:

- Some List

  ```
  Some code. The next line is actually separated by a single blank line.

  See? It displays as two blank lines!
  ```

Comment: This was a different issue, [but is fixed as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists/74115#74115)